# Why does `scala.collection.Iterator ` support `++` but not `:+`?

Tags: scala, iterator, scala-collections, iterable

`scala.collection.Iterator` does not support `:+`

```
scala> Set(0, 2, 3).iterator
res0: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res0 :+ 1
<console>:13: error: value :+ is not a member of Iterator[Int]
       res0 :+ 1
            ^
```

However, since it support `++`, we can implement the similar feature by wrapping the element in an `GenTraversableOnce`

```
scala> res0 ++ Iterator(1)
res2: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res2.toList
res3: List[Int] = List(0, 2, 3, 1)
```

Since the feature can be implemented straightforwardly, why does not Scala standard library provide a `:+` method in `Iterator`?

Comment: I'm not sure of the reason, but you could implement it just like concat is implemented on iterators, but a bit trickier since you need to append or prepend the elements depending on the method.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand the meaning of "you need to append or prepend the elements depending on the method"

Comment: I also don't know the reason, but you can add it yourself: `implicit class IteratorAdd[A](iter: Iterator[A]) { def :+(x: => A) = iter ++ Iterator(x) }`.